# Trigger cell copy (Ctrl+c) programatically with SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, triggers, copy, slickgrid

I am using the `copy/paste` feature implemented in `Slickgrid`'s `slick.cellcopymanager.js` which is working fine (i.e. if you select some cells and press `Ctrl+c` then the content of these cells will be copied into your clipboard).

I would like to trigger the `Ctrl+c` action programatically (for instance to allow doing copy/paste by clicking buttons instead of pressing keys). I know how to define the keydown event for `Ctrl+c`:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
e.which = 67;
e.ctrlKey = true;
```

however I just can't find out which object to trigger that event with and how so as to simulate the manual `Ctrl+c`. First I tried a simple trigger of the event which didn't work:

-`div_dom_from_selected_cell.trigger(e); // nothing happens`
-`grid_dom_wrapper.trigger(e); // nothing happens`
-`$('body').trigger(e); // nothing happens`
-`my_grid.trigger(e); // trigger is not a function`

Then I extended `slick.cellcopymanager.js` so as to make the `handleKeyDown` function available externally:

```
$.extend(this, {
  "init": init,
  "destroy": destroy,
  "clearCopySelection": clearCopySelection,
  "handleKeyDown": handleKeyDown,          // ADDED THIS LINE
  "onCopyCells": new Slick.Event(),
  "onCopyCancelled": new Slick.Event(),
  "onPasteCells": new Slick.Event()
});
```

And tried to use it:

```
var copyManager = new Slick.CellCopyManager();
copyManager.init(my_grid);
copyManager.handleKeyDown(e, { cell: cell, row: row, grid: my_grid } );
```

The copying of the cell still doesn't work despite:
-me having a cell properly selected (it has the `selected` class)
-`handleKeyDown` being fired properly
-`e` and `args` arguments inside `handleKeyDown` looking good (I'm tracing with `console.log` and can't see any difference between manual `Ctrl+c` and programatic attempt`

**How can I trigger the `Ctrl+c` event so as to copy a cell programatically?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me running from the console on the [example page](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html).

```
// Copy from row 2, column 5
var row = 2, col = 5;
grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectedRanges([new Slick.Range(row,col)]);
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
e.which = 67;
e.ctrlKey = true;
grid.onKeyDown.notify(null, e);
```

And then paste:

```
// Past to row 3, column 4
var row = 3, col = 4;
grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectedRanges([new Slick.Range(row,col)]);
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
e.which = 86;
e.ctrlKey = true;
grid.onKeyDown.notify(null, e);
```